# 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter' bug

Tags: ios, swift

I'm initializing a `UICollectionViewController` in `SceneDelegate`:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
      
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let tabBarVC = AppTabBarController()
    
    // I init with a layout here
    let collectionVC = CollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()) 

    collectionVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .favorites, tag: 2)
    tabBarVC.viewControllers = [collectionVC]
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarVC)

    window.rootViewController = navigationController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    self.window = window
}
```

Then I have my UICollectionViewController class:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: UICollectionViewController())
            
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                    
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.automaticallyShowsSearchResultsController = true
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.reuseID)
        collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        collectionView.reloadData()
        
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }
}
```

I initialize my CVC with a layout but I still have the nil layout error which doesn't make any sense:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be
> initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

Comment: Have `var window:UIWindow?` inside `AppDelegate`

Comment: Guess how @Shawn Frank did to solve my issue then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller#:%7E:text=Initializing%20the%20UICollectionViewController%20Object) , these are the valid initializers for a `UICollectionViewController`

> init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout)
>
> init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)
>
> init?(coder: NSCoder)

In your `scene delegate`, this is done fine:

```
let collectionVC
    = CollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

However, in your `CollectionViewController`, you don't use any of the viable initializers when initializing `UISearchController`

```
private let searchController
    = UISearchController(searchResultsController: UICollectionViewController())
```

I believe it is this `UICollectionViewController` you are trying to instantiate with an invalid initializer that is causing your problems